# Not allowing multiple logins at the same time in asp website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a `web portal` and the problem is

> it does not allow many connections at the same time. When a new user logins the previous session is destroyed automatically.

i have even deployed the project but it is of no good as it allows only a single user to login.

here is the `connectionstring` which i am using:

```
  <connectionstrings>
    <add name="ABCConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=435.632.653.322\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ABC;User ID=sa;Password=abcabc" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionstrings>
```

If login is successful it populated the class:

Login_Info.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Login_Info
/// </summary>
public class Login_Info : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Login_Info()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application["name"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application["name"] = value; }
    }

    private string empID;

    public string EmpID
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application["empID"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application["empID"] = value; }
    }

    private string role;

    public string Role
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application["role"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application["role"] = value; }
    }

    private string email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Application["email"] as string; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Application["Email"] = value; }
    }
}
```

The class is populated this way:

```
var login="from a in.......";

    Session["portal"] = login.Email;
                        Role = login.role.ToString();
                        Name = login.Name;
                        EmpID = login.ID.ToString();
                        Email = login.Email;
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What login method is used?

Comment: There are multiple factors here, what authentication are you using, are any exceptions getting thrown? How are you handling sessions? This shouts to me like there is a static class somewhere that is getting set every time a user logs in.

Comment: @cederlof...no, no message is thrown.

Comment: There's far too little information here to work out what the problem is

Comment: @JamieRees...yes i am using a class which stores information on successfult login and from there the session is made.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the source code of your class? Are you using static items?

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino...the values to the class is passed from Query.

Comment: @HaiderKhattak stop commenting, go get your code, and edit your question to include it.  No one is going to be able to help without it.

Comment: @BrendanGreen...Edited...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `HttpContext.Current.Application` for this, as it's not session-specific but available to every client.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.application(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The current state of an application consists of a key/value dictionary
>   of application-wide objects that you can use to store both .NET
>   Framework objects and scalar values that are related to multiple Web
>   requests from multiple clients.

If you want to do authentication this way, consider using `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead.

Or, look at some proper auth mechanisms, like [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity).